# Is there a relation between python open buffering and file.read size parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to optimise the file processing for a service server - reading in chunks, compressing and sending to client. I was wondering whether there is relation between python open()'s buffering parameter and file.read() size parameter.

I've created following test script and was running it with 1MB of randomly generated text and various combination of buffering and size parameters:

```
import sys
import timeit

def main():
    filename = sys.argv[1]
    buffering = int(sys.argv[2])
    chunk_size = int(sys.argv[3])

    print timeit.repeat(stmt=lambda:reading(filename, buffering, chunk_size), repeat=10, number=100)
    exit(0)


def reading(filename, buffering, chunk_size):
    content = []
    with open(filename, 'r', buffering) as f:
        while True:
            chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
            if not chunk:
                break
            process(chunk)
    return

def process(chunk):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Results:

Unbuffered runs:

```
[me@home tmp]$ ./reading.2.py 1mb_test_file 0 -1
[0.022092103958129883, 0.020861148834228516, 0.020159006118774414, 0.020852804183959961, 0.020852804183959961, 0.021064996719360352, 0.020868062973022461, 0.021065950393676758, 0.020724058151245117, 0.019698143005371094]
[me@home tmp]$ ./reading.2.py 1mb_test_file 0 8126
[0.041762113571166992, 0.041918039321899414, 0.041845083236694336, 0.041965007781982422, 0.041656017303466797, 0.041667938232421875, 0.041767120361328125, 0.041543006896972656, 0.041823863983154297, 0.041646957397460938]
[me@home tmp]$ ./reading.2.py 1mb_test_file 0 16384
[0.031350851058959961, 0.030806779861450195, 0.030879974365234375, 0.031160116195678711, 0.030720949172973633, 0.030941009521484375, 0.030817985534667969, 0.031002044677734375, 0.030740022659301758, 0.031502008438110352]
[me@home tmp]$ ./reading.2.py 1mb_test_file 0 4096
[0.063197135925292969, 0.063369989395141602, 0.063393115997314453, 0.063482046127319336, 0.06318211555480957, 0.063271045684814453, 0.063127040863037109, 0.06345677375793457, 0.063257932662963867, 0.063141822814941406]
```

Runs with 8kB buffering parameter:

```
[me@home tmp]$ ./reading.2.py 1mb_test_file 8192 -1
[0.022572994232177734, 0.020329952239990234, 0.021086215972900391, 0.021151065826416016, 0.021051883697509766, 0.021071195602416992, 0.021275043487548828, 0.021074056625366211, 0.020795106887817383, 0.020998954772949219]
[me@home tmp]$ ./reading.2.py 1mb_test_file 8192 8192
[0.042397022247314453, 0.042787075042724609, 0.042707920074462891, 0.042771100997924805, 0.042808055877685547, 0.042753934860229492, 0.042588949203491211, 0.042686223983764648, 0.042527914047241211, 0.042797088623046875]
[me@home tmp]$ ./reading.2.py 1mb_test_file 8192 16384
[0.032326936721801758, 0.032197952270507812, 0.031965017318725586, 0.031849861145019531, 0.032578945159912109, 0.032018899917602539, 0.031890869140625, 0.032000064849853516, 0.031239032745361328, 0.032066822052001953]
[me@home tmp]$ ./reading.2.py 1mb_test_file 8192 4096
[0.06818699836730957, 0.062704086303710938, 0.061124086380004883, 0.049216985702514648, 0.062672138214111328, 0.067947864532470703, 0.067732810974121094, 0.068349838256835938, 0.068238019943237305, 0.068017005920410156]
```

Runs with 16kB buffering size:

```
[me@home tmp]$ ./reading.2.py 1mb_test_file 16384 -1
[0.022460222244262695, 0.021178960800170898, 0.021303176879882812, 0.020936012268066406, 0.020729780197143555, 0.017519950866699219, 0.014748811721801758, 0.020572185516357422, 0.020045042037963867, 0.020984888076782227]
[me@home tmp]$ ./reading.2.py 1mb_test_file 16384 16384
[0.031231880187988281, 0.031037092208862305, 0.031080961227416992, 0.030995845794677734, 0.030937910079956055, 0.031276226043701172, 0.031119823455810547, 0.030817985534667969, 0.031432151794433594, 0.030987977981567383]
[me@home tmp]$ ./reading.2.py 1mb_test_file 16384 32768
[0.026186943054199219, 0.025575160980224609, 0.026786088943481445, 0.025743007659912109, 0.025722026824951172, 0.025857925415039062, 0.024456977844238281, 0.024057149887084961, 0.025676965713500977, 0.025729179382324219]
[me@home tmp]$ ./reading.2.py 1mb_test_file 16384 8192
[0.054841041564941406, 0.046918153762817383, 0.046893119812011719, 0.046890020370483398, 0.046682119369506836, 0.046760082244873047, 0.04701995849609375, 0.046629905700683594, 0.047094106674194336, 0.046594142913818359]
```

If I read the results correctly, it is better to have read size bigger then buffering value, and read file in one go (if you can stand it memory wise). Alternatively, it seems that using 16kB for buffering and 32kB for read size give me almost the performance of reading a file in one go.

So, my questions:

- Is my test script correct? Do I need to clear the cache? How?
- Is there alternative way to get 16kB/32kB values - e.g. from system settings?

Thanks,
M.

Comment: I'm not sure your test is valid, since your process function is just a pass - presumably your real process function has some overhead and you may find it's better to call it more often with smaller chunks, or once with a huge chunk. Presumably your process step will take much longer (computationally) than (presumably-local) file IO?

Comment: Yes, the compression would take some time, but I'm not sure how would that affect file IO.

Comment: It doesn't. What I am getting at is if running your process command takes 100 seconds longer if you use the optimal IO params (e.g. because you are calling it with lots of small chunks), then it might not make sense to use the optimal IO params.

Comment: Or to put it another way, it might make sense to decouple the chunking of the file reading from the chunking of the process command. My gut feel would be to use the OS-default for file buffering, and use a relatively large read size (32kB or more sounds fine, but if you're then sending the data over the network you might want to optimise that part for latency/throughput/whatever separately).

Comment: I'm using asynchronous framework, so decoupling of file reading and processing might be an option. Also, I did not want to include processing to the "process" function to avoid impact on the timings.